# Do listeners create memory leaks if not removed from a destroyed activity?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-activity

If you add a listener to a control/view and do not remove it, will that create a memory leak? For example, `onCreate` adds a listener to an `EditText` that listens for modifications. Do you need to remove this listener in the onDestroy?

I imagine that if you use an anonymous listener or a local variable that implements the listener, the memory would be free'd when the `Activity` is destroyed due to scoping rules.

The only way I could see a memory leak potential is if the listener was passed in an intent object. Thoughts?

Comment: When you pass an object via intent extras, the instance of the object is not passed.  A copy of the object is created using the serializable or parcelable interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By themselves, listener do not create a memory leak. However, they're often used improperly and so may lead to leaks. Sometimes you see code where an object refers to a Component (e.g. for displaying messages there), which has a listener, which refers (possibly indirectly) to the first object. This forms a cycle and all its members live and die together. When the Component is a dialog which is meant to be short-living, you may have a problem. Beginners tend to use objects like

```
class MyKitchenSink implements Runnable, KeyListener, ....
```

which may have a lot of references and makes it easier to build a memory leak<sup>*</sup>. Not creating "universal classes" is the way to go.

---

<sup>*</sup> It's no "real" memory leak like in `C`, since all the objects stays reachable and could be used if you wanted to. It's just keeping object reachable for a much longer time than expected, which eats you memory just like a leak.

Answer (score 3):

A memory leak should not be created unless something other than the control/view references the listener - no need to remove the listener in the onDestroy...

Comment: and this answer is based on? Just curious, I could guess at the answer but I'm looking for a solid answer.

Comment: @Spidy Thats how garbage collection works. If nothing references an object, it can be destroyed.  Thus, if the only things referencing a listener are within the view, and the view is destroyed, the listener can also be destroyed.  See this article for more details on memory leaks in java: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-leaks/

Comment: @Spidy just do a simple experiment: create a simple app with activity that has an EditText. Add onTextChange listener to that editText and rotate your device multiple times. While doing so record you CPU in Android Studio Profiler and you will see that all instances of your activity/fragment are cleaned at some point. It may not be done instantly but GC knows best when to clean the heap.