# Remove all the listeners from a view android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, memory-leaks

In order to avoid memory leaks I want to remove all the listeners and the watchers from an android view. For the TextWatcher, I know I have to save each reference added with addTextChangedListener() in a data structure and remove it later (in the onDestroy) with removeTextChangedListener(). But for the other listeners of a view, is there a way that I can find them all to set them to null.
So far I have been using this on most of my views (**EDIT:** all the views that has been assigned any listener; plus this is called in onDestroy() and/or in onDestroyView() depending on the case):

```
 public static  void releaseView(View view){
        if(view != null ){
            view.removeCallbacks(null);
            if(!(view instanceof AdapterView)) {
                view.setOnClickListener(null);
                view.setOnTouchListener(null);
                view.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                view.setOnDragListener(null);
                view.setOnFocusChangeListener(null);
                view.setOnKeyListener(null);

                if (view instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) view).setOnEditorActionListener(null);
                    ((TextView) view).setKeyListener(null);


                    if(view instanceof CheckBox)
                        ((CheckBox) view).setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                }
            }
            else {
                if (view instanceof ListView) {
                    ((ListView) view).setOnItemClickListener(null);
                    ((ListView) view).setOnItemLongClickListener(null);
                    ((ListView) view).setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
                    ((ListView) view).setOnScrollListener(null);
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) //if Marshamallow => API 23
                        ((ListView) view).setOnScrollChangeListener(null);
                    ((ListView) view).setAdapter(null);
                    //return;
                }

                if (view instanceof Spinner) {
                    ((Spinner) view).setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
                    //return;
                }

                if (view instanceof GridView) {
                    ((GridView) view).setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
                    ((GridView) view).setAdapter(null);                       
                }
            }          
        }
    }
```

Yet I still get some the views called by this method leaked. Is there anything that I am missing. Can someone please correct me if I made a mistake here.

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace for your suspicious memory leaks? Because in android, all views are associated with almost no listeners at all.

Comment: @Maddy Blaklisted, in android each and every time that you assign a listener to a view, you have to clear it(set that listener to null)  to avoid any memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, almost all of the listeners in views are null by default, until you initialize any.

So setting null is **absolutely unnecessary**

Why do you think there is a memory leak. Is there any error log?

Comment: I call this method on every view that has been assigned a listener. When in an activity it is called in onDestroy() when in a fragment it is called in onDestroyView(). I think there is a memory leak because of the trace in Java Heap Dump

Answer (score 0):

Usually listeners don't cause any memory leaks **unless** you create or manipulate them **improperly** in such a way that they create any cyclic or circular references in memory. More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238321/do-listeners-create-memory-leaks-if-not-removed-from-a-destroyed-activity)!

If you create and / or use listeners properly, you are never needed to remove the listeners unnecessarily.

It is further recommended to go through the [Official Android Documentation for Avoiding Memory Leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)! for further assistance.