# Is it better to set listeners in onViewCreated or onStart? (Fragments)

Tags: android

Should I set listeners in my onCreate(View) methods or in onStart and when setting them in onStart, should I remove them again in the onPause method?
Is there any downside to do it in onCreate(View) and not remove them?
Should I differ between View listeners and other listeners?

**EDIT:** I looks like it is better to use onViewCreated() instead of onCreateView() for listeners. Still, is it better to use onViewCreated() or onStart()?
Maybe it is more important to know if it is necessary to remove listeners or not.

**EDIT:** I looked into stuff about memory leaks and it looks like it's ok to use the listeners in onViewCreated() but I didn't find any official solution or suggestion
The following links helped me about this problem

[Do listeners create memory leaks if not removed from a destroyed activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238321/do-listeners-create-memory-leaks-if-not-removed-from-a-destroyed-activity)

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Comment: yeah, but there is no real answer

Comment: That thread has no real answer, and no explanation why one would be better, especially that thread is only about Activities, no Fragments mentioned there.
And I just got found it, after I posted my question, which is funny because normally StackOverflow should suggest me that thread before I post something, not after

Comment: I do it in `onViewCreated()`, but many people do it in `onCreateView()` before returning inflated view. There is no real answer to this. Google does it in both of these ways. This depends on how you want to structure your code.

Comment: onViewCreated SGTM
never used it before, but it should work nicely with kotlinx.

Comment: Shouldn't we be using `onAttach(context)` and `onDetach()` methods for setting and removing listeners,respectively, inside fragments?

Comment: Didn't think, about that, too. That would get rid of a lot of set listener calls

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes but it is called even before onCreate, there is no view yet, to set all the listeners

Comment: I referred this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) on how to communicate from fragment to activity. Have a look.

Comment: Ah, true, callback listeners to the Activity are created in onAttach, but there are no views to set listeners, in Fragments we have to wait at least until onCreateView

Comment: Sorry man, I use Butterknife in most of my projects, so I really don't attach view listeners to handle event callbacks myself--I just let the library handle it.

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes Since I am using Kotlin, I don't feel the need for Butterknife anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164460/discussion-between-musab-kurt-and-when-the-morning-comes).

Answer (score -2):

onViewCreated() is the best place to set all listeners and if you talk about on onStart() you can't get any view so it will throw NullPointerException.

Comment: That is actually not true. 
onStart would not throw a NullPointerExeption
and you can refer to your views in onCreateView by using the rootView, not the best solution, but it works